# What is the difference between let and let*, I dont understand this (Racket)

Tags: racket, let

```
(define x 2)

(let ((x 1) (y (+ x 1))) (+ x y))
```

you get 4;

```
(let* ((x 1) (y (+ x 1))) (+ x y))
```

you get 3.

I do not understand how the `let` thing works. Could someone please explain, i'm new to computer science thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
(let ((x 0) (z x))
  ...)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
((lambda (x z) ...) 0 x)
```

Perhaps in the anonymous procedure call you can see that when the arguments are evaluated the variable inside the body does not exist yet, but inside the body `x` is `0` and the previous `x` is shadowed in the whole body but accesible as `z`.

```
(let* ((x 0) (z x))
  ...)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
(let ((x 0))
  (let ((z x))
    ...))
```

Looking at this you see right away that `x` gets set to `0` and shadows any other `x` at the time `z` gets bound.

Imagine you want to calculate the hypothenus og a triangle:

```
(let ((hypotenuse (sqrt (+ (square a) (square b)))))
  ...)
```

You want to split it up a little so you change it to a `let*` like this:

```
(let* ((sqa (square a))
       (sqb (square b))
       (hypotenuse (sqrt sqa sqb)))
  ...)
```

If you woudl have used `let` then `sqa` and `sqb` wuldn't be available!
The rule of thumb is to use `let` and change it to a `let*` when you need to reference something bound in the same `let`. Be careful to not shadow variables you are using later.